Which school do muggle born wizards/witches living near Durmstrang attend?
Draco was telling his gang that muggle born wizards/witches were not allowed to enter Durmstrang.

"...Father actually considered sending me to Durmstrang rather than
Hogwarts, you know. He knows the headmaster, you see. Well, you know
his opinion of Dumbledore - the man's such a Mudblood-lover - and
Durmstrang doesn't admit that sort of riffraff. But Mother didn't like
the idea of me going to school so far away. Father says Durmstrang
takes a far more sensible line than Hogwarts about the Dark Arts.
Durmstrang students actually learn them, not just the defense rubbish
we do...."

So which school do the muggle born witches/wizards living near Durmstrang  attend?

Presumably the various schools are not so strict about the geographic location their students come from. If Malfoy, from Britain, could have attended Durmstrang (but for his mother’s reservations), it stands to reason that students from the Durmstrang area could attend Hogwarts or one of the other schools.
Indeed, at the end of Goblet of Fire, Dumbledore announces that the students from Durmstrang would always be welcome at Hogwarts:

“Every guest in this Hall,” said Dumbledore, and his eyes lingered upon the Durmstrang students, “will be welcomed back here at any time, should they wish to come.

